# Can I set up a private and secure SQLite database on an iOS or Android phone?

Tags: android, ios, sqlite, xamarin

I have an application that stores its data and test results in a SQLite database on either and Android or ios phone.

Is it possible to secure this data so that only the application can access it or is the data open to anyone (that knows how) to go in and make changes to the database?

Answer (score 1):

You could look into encrypting your db. There are libraries like [SQLCipher](https://www.zetetic.net/sqlcipher/) you could look into.

Answer (score 1):

Since the database is just a file in SQLite, if other apps can't access that file you're good. 
If you mean accessing it by tinkering with the filesystem, it's definitely possible on Android, unless you encrypt the file. On iOS it's a bit more difficult, but on a jailbroken phone it's entirely possible as well.

You'd want to research SQLite encryption libraries, but these are different on iOS and Android. If you want a common approach, encrypt the file and decrypt it before access.

[SQLCipher](https://www.zetetic.net/sqlcipher/sqlcipher-for-android/) is a popular library for encrypting your db on Android.
You should definitely enable Proguard as well if you're worried about modifications to your app.

Answer (score 0):

> Is the data open to anyone (that knows how) to go in and make changes
>   to the database?

Yes:

- Jailbroken iPhone,iPad.
- Rooted Android device.

> Is it possible to secure this data so that only the application can
>   access it?

Not really but you can make it harder to leak through encrypting all the sensitive informations. Note: Do not use an opensource Encryption/Decryption chances are that the hacker also knows about it and it will be used againts you. Implements your own Encryption and Decryption instead if you have time.